# Unable to upgrade from 20.04.2 to 20.04.3

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, dell, xps

I recently bought a Dell Laptop with Ubuntu 20.04.2 pre-installed in it. After my first time login, it did update a few software packages, but I was still at 20.04.2 at the end of it. I tried apt-get update && apt-get upgrade / apt-get dist-upgrade through the terminal, but still no effect.

Considering 20.04.3 is already released end of August, shouldn't I be getting it when trying to do the above update + upgrade? From the GUI 'Software & Updates', I had set Notify me of a new Ubuntu version (For long-term support versions). But even the GUI updater says my software is up-to-date.

Not sure what I am missing here. Here are some details:

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (fossa-bulbasaur X55.1)
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux dev-linux 5.10.0-1045-oem #47-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 18 10:41:03 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`sudo apt-get update`:

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                                                                                                      
Hit:3 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial InRelease                                                                                                           
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                         
Hit:5 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                               
Hit:6 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                       
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                   
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/timeshift/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                       
Hit:9 http://oem.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:10 http://dell.archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                                                                   
Hit:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                    
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]       
Hit:13 https://packages.teejeetech.com/aptik/0/OTKti8icDT/ubuntu/focal/amd64 stable InRelease
Hit:14 https://packages.teejeetech.com/battery-monitor/free/ubuntu/focal/amd64 stable InRelease
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [29.0 kB]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [62.5 kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,256 kB]               
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [544 kB]
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [283 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [641 kB]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [864 kB]
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [361 kB]
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [220 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.4 kB]
Fetched 4,603 kB in 3s (1,316 kB/s)                                    
Reading package lists... Done
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

`sudo apt list --upgradable`:

```
Listing... Done
```

**Edit 1**

- Commented out all unofficial sources in /etc/apt/*.list
- Performed `sudo apt clean`

Still the same problem:

`sudo apt update`:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                            
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                               
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Fetched 328 kB in 2s (207 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

`sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: @Nmath Yes I understand it is just another point release of the same release. And this is exactly why I am confused why a simple apt update + upgrade is not able to get it. Anyway I updated the full output of apt-get update. And whatever output I already posted for apt upgrade, that is what I am getting still.

Comment: How do you have Linux kernel 5.10?  This is not the correct kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 for HWE or GA.

Comment: The new laptop came with Ubuntu pre-installed in it. And since then I didn't do anything in terms of kernel version. The only update that was done is via a GUI notification that I got that some packages are available for update.

Comment: Hmmm... I see one xenial repo that might be problematic but I would expect there to be an error if that is the case. Can you go under `/etc/apt` and check `sources.list` and any other source lists.  If you comment out unofficial sources with `#` before each line, then run `sudo apt clean` and then try `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` again. You can uncomment the lines after you try this. You can also make a backup of these source lists or just make a note which ones you commented so you can change them back.

Comment: So, the master /etc/apt/sources.list is untouched. I do see a bunch of lists under /etc/apt/sources.list.d (created by my laptop OEM and other software). Are you suggesting that I move everything under sources.list.d to a backup directory.

Then run `sudo apt clean` followed by `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`? 

After that, I can bring them back? 

Thank you for looking into this issue and helping me.

Comment: You can make a copy to restore it if necessary.  I am suggesting to edit the lists and add a `#` before each line that is not an official Ubuntu source. `apt clean` will purge the apt cache and you may get different updates the next time you run `apt update`. If it doesn't work you can just restore the backups or just remove the `#` that you added.  If things look really weird after `apt update` and you aren't sure, it won't change anything unless you proceed with `apt upgrade` anyway.  If that happens, don't proceed with `apt upgrade` and post the details here in an edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130202/discussion-between-linuxmonk-and-nmath).

Comment: Do you found solution? I have exactly the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Dell Laptop that came with 18.04 preinstalled. I was able to upgrade to 20.04.2 but somehow got stuck there, perhaps related to me trying to install winehq PPAs.

Here's how I fixed it (all actions require 'root'):

- Launch "software-properties" (the purple "Software Updates" icon).
- In the section "**Updates**", change "*For other packages, subscribe to*:" from "Custom" to "**All updates**".
- Close the app, making sure to save the changes if prompted.

From the command line, when performing "`apt update && apt -u dist-upgrade`" I received about 1GB of updates.

If this doesn't work for you, I also selected the checkbox to enable "*Pre-released updates (focal-proposed)*." under "**Developer Options**" but a commenter below says this is unnecessary and may be undesirable.

Now - for me - the Dell installation had used `dpkg-divert` to replace `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs` with a *disable* script. This means that the initial ramdisk won't be generated for the new kernels. Without that your system will not be able to boot by default, though you can still select the old kernel from the GRUB boot menu.

If this is your case, to re-enable initramfs you can probably use `dpkg-divert`, but I manually restored the saved file: `mv /usr/sbin/update-initramfs.distrib /usr/sbin/update-initramfs`. Then I ran `update-initramfs -c -k all` and `update-grub2` to get a bootable system.

And you didn't ask, but yes - now your system can install and run `perf`.

[Post edited for clarity.]

Comment: Hello. Adding this is a bad idea and was not needed. Under "Developer Options" I also selected the checkbox to enable "Pre-released updates (focal-proposed)."

Comment: Hi @David, which part is a bad idea and not needed? Did the rest work for you? I got a comment that I should make the text clearer so if you could clarify I can make a better response.

Comment: Using pre release